# .NET web app cant run SQL queries

Tags: .net, sql-server, web, configuration

I have a website on a laptop to show a client, the laptop has IIS 6 and SQL Server 2008, the same set up as my development pc.
Although everything work fine on the dev pc I can't get the site to run queries against SQL.

It will show data in dropdowns, but when I try to run queries I get an error which looks as if the connection string is wrong, which I don't think it is.  Ive been trying for a week to sort this, Ive tried all the SQL config changes, named pipes, using NT AUTHORITY\network service user for the app pool, and a few things beside.  Is there anything anyone else has heard of to sort this?  Or anything else I could check?

my web config connection string

```
<add name="eisConnectionString" 
    connectionString="data source=lapgha11863\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=eis;Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and the error returned from .NET

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   "

Comment: The error message claims it's trying to use named pipes, but that's not part of the connection string you posted. Is it using the connection string you think it is?

Comment: pretty certain it is yeah, the code in the app and the name of the conn string haven't changed but it only does not work on the laptop

Comment: Joel Coehoorn, unless specified otherwise, SqlClient will try to connect using TCP/IP and fall back to named pipes if the connection fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using integrated security, the Website needs to run in the context of a user which also has permissions to the database. Follow these steps:

Create a new User on the machine, remove them from the Users Group and the Administrators group. Add the user to the IIS_IUSRS group.

Set this user on the Identity of the app pool.

In SSMS go to security, add the Windows User.

Go to the User properties > User mapping and select the database. and save that.

Go back to the user mapping, highlight the database and make the user db_owner

Make sure the connection string data source in the web.config points to the correcr instance of SQL Server or /SQLExpress, you can use a "." for the local machine or .\SQLExpress etc.

Comment: What about the app pool identity? I had already done what you've put I your post.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry missed that step, the same user needs to be set as the Identity on the app pool, updated answer.

Comment: Usually that should do it.. otherwise double check the connection string, database name and connection string name.

Comment: Ok, user set up and added to SQL an app pool, and iis_iusrs, still the same problem.  If using integrated security in my config should I then also be logged on to the laptop as that user also?

Comment: No, you don't need to be logged in as that user. .. and "eisConnectionString" is used by your code to create the connection in your data access code? Also maybe try adding the 
<clear /> tag before adding the eisConnectionString connection string.

Comment: eisConnectionString is used for the sql datasources for dropdowns (they work), queries are done using LINQ / dbml.  Connection string for this also seems correct

Comment: If the code work on your dev machine and you've set it up, I suspect there is something else within the enviroment, you could check the correct .net framework is installed and selected in the App Pool settings. also try running the iis installation/registration tool for the correct version:  <..framwork>/aspnet_regiis.exe -i
Failing that, install visual studio on the laptop and see it runs there?

Comment: ok, just saw your comment change from No to Yes on the Entity Framework... in this case you may need to add an additional connection string that supports the Model to enable the Entity framework data context to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change lapgha11863 in data source=lapgha11863\sqlexpress  for the computer name of your laptop and sqlexpress for the name of the instance of SQL on the laptop.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse for examples of connection strings.

Comment: Already done, what's in the connection string is correct, what I don't get is that drop downs appear populated and that data comes from the database, it's just any selects/inserts etc that don't run

Comment: @Theresa "data comes from the database, it's just any selects/inserts etc that don't run" - the error message you posted is an error during connection to the database, not during a select or insert.

Comment: @Joe, I get what what the error means, I just can't work out why I would see data in the drop downs, which use the same connection string, but have problems trying to do anything else, I've never seen this before.  Thanks